# Sequence puzzle: 3, 9, 27

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

A twist of the classic sequence game:

A friend asked me to find the rule to this sequence: 3, 9, 27.

I am allowed to suggest other sequences to test if they follow that (unknown to me) rule, to which my friend can say yes or no. Once I think I got the rule I can say it.

Here are the sequences I tried and his answer:

| Sequence | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 2 3 | No |
| 3 6 9 | No |
| 3 27 81 | Yes |
| 9 27 81 | Yes |
| 3 9 81 | No |
| 3 9 27 81 | Yes |
| 81 9 27 3 | Yes |
| -6 -8 -2 | Yes |
| -8 -2 -6 | Yes |
| -2 -6 -8 | Yes |
| 3 5 0 | No |
| 3 5 10 11 | No |
| 3 5 11 | No |
| 3 6 11 | Yes |
| 19 6 11 | Yes |
| 3 5 12 | No |
| 5 5 5 | No |
| 6 6 6 | Yes |
| pi 4 8 | Not Consistent |

Can you determine the rule to generate the sequence?

Comment: What does "Not Consistent" mean? (That whatever rule is in play only _makes sense_ when applied to certain sequences, and that isn't one of them?)

Comment: "Not Consistent" probably means that terms need to be integers.

Comment: Observation: Every single example contains a number that is a multiple of 3, except for 5 5 5 (no). This is only about 1% likely, if he were sampling numbers randomly for his examples. I mean it's already obvious he's not, but 3 is still a notable fixation.